# Determine if ActiveCell is in a specific table

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to determine by VBA in Excel 2013 if the ActiveCell is not just in any table, but in a specific table.

Below is the code as is, but only detects ActiveCell being in any table. The commented out line is what I'm looking for, but obviously it doesn't work.

```
    ...
    Set rng = Intersect(.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObject.DataBodyRange)
    'Set rng = Intersect(.EntireRow, ActiveCell.ListObjects("myTable").DataBodyRange)
    On Error GoTo 0
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Please select the cell of a row within the consensus input table.", vbCritical, "Delete Evaluator"
        Else
    ...
```

Any suggestions on the right syntax for this?

Thanks!

Comment: No line is commented out XD

Comment: Look at the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) of both the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) and the ListObject table's [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx).

Comment: Why are you using `ActiveCell`?  It can be very temperamental

Comment: Considering the high percentage of ActiveCell's that will NOT be in the ListObject table's DataBodyRange, perhaps you should give some consideration as to what you want to happen on an error?

Comment: @findwindow - Added comment, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Chrismas007 - My only other thought is to use Selection, but why use that when I can use ActiveCell...? The idea here is you click on any cell on the row of the table you want to delete, then click the delete command button that runs a macro to delete the row and adjust everything on the sheet accordingly.

Comment: @Jeeped - Currently if the button is clicked while ActiveCell is outside of the table, it pops up a warning message and nothing happens. I don't really want to Select the table because the user has "Delete" in mind and I want to avoid mistakes. Is that what you're getting at? Or were you thinking something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To test if *ActiveCell* is in the body of *Table1*:

```
Sub qwerty()

   If Intersect(ActiveCell, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "activecell not in Table1"
   Else
      MsgBox "activecell in Table1"
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8):

A more general solution, adaptable to other tables

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim lo As ListObject

    Set r = ActiveCell
    Set lo = r.ListObject
    If Not lo Is Nothing Then
        Select Case lo.Name
            Case "Table1"
                If r.Row = lo.Range.Row Then
                    MsgBox "In Table1 Header"
                Else
                    MsgBox "In Table1 Body"
                End If
            Case "SomeOtherTable"
                '...
        End Select
    Else
        MsgBox "Not in any table"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A good answer, but goes too far for what I am intending here and can accomplish in fewer lines. Will keep in mind for future use though if the situation arises.

Comment: Thank you!! `Range.ListObject` is what I was looking for! (I've been searching for a long time to get the table from any cell).

Answer (score 7):

Generally, we're interested in work being performed within the DataBodyRange of a table and Excel provides us a shortcut for that area of a Table. For a table named "myTable", you directly access the DataBodyRange in code using `[myTable]`.

Thus, for inclusive table location testing of the ActiveCell one could test as follows:

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, [myTable]) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Love this. Simple and intuitive. Thanks. ➕1️

Answer (score 3):

A `Range` object has a `ListObject` property that will return the table of the Range.  All you have to do is to test if the cell is in any table:

```
If ActiveCell.ListObject Is Nothing Then
    ...
```

and see if it is in your specific table:

```
If ActiveCell.ListObject.Name = "MyTable" Then
    ...
```

and you're done!

Much cleaner than using `Application.Intersect(...)`.  [chris neilsen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445425/chris-neilsen) answer alludes to this as well.

Comment: This is very useful. But not the best answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following line of code:

```sql
    ActiveCell.ListObject.Name
```

or sub:

```sql
    Sub IsActiveCellInTable()
    'If active cell in table then get name'
    Dim strTblName As String

        'Disable error checking'
        On Error Resume Next 

        strTblName = ActiveCell.ListObject.Name

        'Reset error checking'
        On Error GoTo 0 

        If strTblName <> "" Then
            MsgBox "Cell (" & ActiveCell.Address & ") is included in: " & strTblName
        Else
            MsgBox "Cell (" & ActiveCell.Address & ") is not included in table."
        End If

    End Sub
```