# Determine if a range is already a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue that has been bugging me on and off for the last few days.

I have a worksheet with 100's of tables on, and a code that will insert more data onto that worksheet as it runs.

The idea is to then convert that added data to tables. However I run into a few problems with this.

I shall try and explain my current method, I have a for loop that can easily select the data in each of the current tables and the new data that has been added, using the `.find` method based upon `i` being Odd or Even. I then run down the spearsheet (as all the data is in the same column.) At this point I run into a world of trouble.

Firstly I tried to select the range of data that should be a table ( Sometimes it is, other it's not) and convert to table. This didnt work as I found out you are unable to force a table to become the same table again.

Secondly I tried to use `On Errors` to get around this. I tried to unlist the range as a table, then if there was an error i.e. the range was not a table then goto the section that makes the range a table, and if the Selected range was a table to then remove the table from the range and the re-format the range as a table.

At this point I was out of ideas. Below is my code for my second attempt.

```
If i Mod 2 = 0 Then ' This is to select the New Range '

            j = j + 1 ' Used to name the tabels '

            Set TableRange = Range(Cells(StartRow, 6), Cells(EndRow - 1, 13)) ' Selectst the table range '

            TableRange.Select ' Selects the tabels '

            On Error GoTo AddTable:

                ActiveSheet.ListOnjects.Items(1).Unlist

AddTable:

            ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TableRange, , xlYes).Name = "Table" & j ' Formats the selected range as a table and names the table '
            Range("Table" & j & "[#All]").Select ' Selects the table '
            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table" & j).TableStyle = "TableStyleLight15" ' Sets the table style '

        End If
```

I have tried to comment the code as best as possible as well as giving you a background into what my thought process was. I expect there are far simpler ways to do this, but not that I can think off.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Might be a able to adapt this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076540/determine-if-activecell-is-in-a-specific-table You might have to loop all listobjects addresses in the sheet first and store those in an array for example then compare any given range with those in the array using a loop

Comment: `ActiveSheet.ListOnjects` `ListObjects`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where ws.Range("A1:C8") is a table (the entire table including headers). Uses a function to return True if table else False

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim testRange As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set testRange = ws.Range("A1:C8")

    If IsTable(testRange, ws) Then
        Debug.Print "Table"
    Else

    End If

End Sub
Public Function IsTable(ByVal testRange As Range, ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Boolean

Dim table As ListObject
Dim tableAddresses() As String
ReDim tableAddresses(ws.ListObjects.Count)
Dim counter As Long

For Each table In ws.ListObjects

    tableAddresses(counter) = table.Range.Address 'or databody range depending on your requirements
    counter = counter + 1
Next table

Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(tableAddresses) To UBound(tableAddresses)

    If testRange.Address = tableAddresses(i) Then
        IsTable = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

New data can be added to a `ListObject` using any of these two options:

1. Posting the new data in the next row immediately after the last row of the `ListObject`. The `ListObject` automatically resizes to include the new rows.
2. Resizing the `Range` of the `ListObject` to include the new rows. Note that when resizing a `ListObject` the `Header` must remain in the same row.

To validate if any `Cell` in a `Range` is part of a `ListObject` use the `ListObject` property of the range:
Set lo = rg.ListObject

I would also suggest declaring the variables and the use of Objects, so lines like this: `ActiveSheet.ListOnjects.Items(1).Unlist` would be written as: `ws.ListOnjects.Items(1).Unlist`. Then when compiling or running the procedures, spelling errors will be highlighted, given you the opportunity to do corrections such as: `ws.ListObjects(1).Unlist`. To force the declaration of variables and syntax check see fig. below.

[image]

As regards the `Style` of the `ListObject` you can set it by default for a `workbook` using this line:

```
    wb.DefaultTableStyle = "TableStyleLight15" 'where wb is the workbook object
```

or it can be set when adding the `ListObject` as in:

```
    ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rg, , xlYes, , "TableStyleLight15")
```

Try this procedure:

```
Sub Range_ListObject_Resizing()
Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range, lo As ListObject
Dim lRowIni As Long, lRowEnd As Long, i As Integer

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Parent.DefaultTableStyle = "TableStyleLight15"

    lRowIni = 3     'change as required
    lRowEnd = 20    'change as required

    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then

        Rem Set Objects
        Set rg = ws.Range(Cells(lRowIni, 6), Cells(lRowEnd - 1, 13))
        Set lo = rg.ListObject

        Rem Validate ListObject
        If Not (lo Is Nothing) Then
            lo.Resize rg
            lo.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight15"

        Else
            Set lo = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rg, , xlYes)

    End If: End If

    End Sub
```